# Is it necessary for a minor to show a driving log when obtaining a driver license?

Tags: licensing, driving, minor, oregon

In Oregon, a minor who has not completed a driver education course needs to obtain an instruction permit and complete 100 hours of driving supervised by a person 21 years old or older who has been a licensed driver for at least three years. [ORS 807.065](https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_807.065) (1)(d) and (1)(e). Does "certify[ing]" this require showing a driving log at the DMV office, a written statement, or a verbal statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to keep a written log. You can download a blank log [here](https://www.oregon.gov/odot/DMV/Teen/Documents/teen_drive_log.pdf) (pdf format).

> Print and use this log to keep track of your teen’s behind-the-wheel
> practice and their progress toward becoming a safe driver! Keep this
> log in your vehicle and write down every time you and your teen
> practice driving. Individuals under 18 need at least 50 hours of
> supervised driving practice if they have taken an ODOT-approved driver
> education course. Without the course, 100 hours of supervised driving
> practice is required.

```
Date | Session Topic/Focus | Time (Hours/Min) | Cumulative Hours | Teen’s Initials | Adult’s Initials
```

In the DMV's brochure, [The Road to Getting Your License](https://www.oregon.gov/odot/Safety/Documents/Road_to_Getting_Your_License.pdf), there is this FAQ:

> Q. How do I certify my hours of supervised driving practice?
>
> A. You will need to keep a driving log to track your hours. You and
> your parent or legal guardian must certify driving hours at DMV when
> getting your license.

Comment: Yes, I know they recommend that, but I don't see that the law actually requires that. Will they refuse to give me a license if I certify that I have driven 100 hours but do I not have a log?

Comment: that's what they say in a licensing brochure faq although it's implied not explicit. I'll update my answer to include it.

Comment: sorry, it is explicitly stated that you need to keep a log. speculation: they used to let parent or guardian swear that the hours had been done, but then realized that many people were lying and the teens were getting into accidents. Requiring a log may have reduced accidents.